# Why this parseInt throws array out of bound exception?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I was trying to find GCD of two arguments but at line 36 it throws ArrayOutOfBoundsException

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>     at Hcdno.main(Gcdno.java:36)

```
public class Gcdno {         
    static int gcd(int a,int b)
    {
        if(a==b)
            return a;
        if(a==0 || b==0)
            return 0;
        if(a>b)
            return hcd(a-b,b);
        return hcd(a,b-a);            
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int o=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int x= gcd(m,o);
        System.out.println(x); 
    }      
}
```

Comment: The exception says the error occurred on line 36.  I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's when you're doing `args[0]` or `args[1]`.  You don't check the length of the provided arguments.  Unless you run your program `java Gcdno arg0 arg1` (eg with 2 or more arguments) you will get this exception.

Comment: There is no definition of `hcd`. Is it a typo here, on in the actual program as well?

Comment: Check the length of `args` before trying to use an index of the array.

Comment: To elaborate on Ian's point, it's very important for future debugging to realize that the exception did _not_ come from parseInt. It came from an expression near parseInt in the code (namely, the expression that was going to be parseInt's argument, if that expression had succeeded), but parseInt never got invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error as the `String[] args` is empty.

Whenever you run a Java program using command prompt and want to pass arguments then `String[] args` is used. I think you are not running the Java program from command prompt or if you are then you are not passing the arguments and thus you are getting the mentioned error as `String[] args` array is empty.
Since you want to get value of m and o you can use the following:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int m= scan.nextInt();
int o = scan.nextInt();
```

Now when you run your Java program it will wait for input from you and after that execute.

Comment: Thankew for ur suggestion...Cant, we use IDE to pass arguments?..as it also works same as command prompt with additional features.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error. Cause you are not given a value for the args argument of the method.

You can run the application with below format

Suppose the file path of compiled Gcdno class is "/home/himly/Gcdno.class"

Run following commands

```
cd  /home/himly
java Gcdno 8 7
```

Comment: And I recommend you to  rewrite your application by the way of the @Yug Singh answered

Comment: `8, 7` Why there is a **comma** between?

Comment: @Hearen Thank you for you remind me. I will re-edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for you:

**If you are using an IDE to do the building/running tasks, you'd better use the second option.**

# 1. enclose the numbers when starting the program

In this case, you need to go to the directory holding the java program and run:

```
javac Gcdno.java 
java Gcdno 3 5
```

# 2. use [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to get the input from users

In your case you can try:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int m=scanner.nextInt();
int o=scanner.nextInt();
```

By the way, your `gcd` method has some typo issues. I fixed it as:

```
static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) return a;
    if (a == 0 || b == 0) return 0;
    if (a > b) return gcd(a - b, b); // not hcd;
    return gcd(a, b - a); // not hcd;
}
```